# How to show data using react

Tags: reactjs, spotify, styled-components

you are currently using react to replicate Spotify.

You are currently developing a search function and have successfully received a response.

I want to show this on the screen.

How do I solve this? Please help me.

```
const onClick = () => {
    const inputSearchData = sessionStorage.getItem('inputData');
    const inputTypeData = sessionStorage.getItem('inputType');

// console.log(inputTypeData)
axios({
    headers: {  
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`,
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/search',
    params: {
        q: inputSearchData,
        type: inputTypeData,
    },
}).then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
    
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
})
```

}

Comment: Share your React code

Answer (score 0):

1. when you get your response from your `axios` request you need to store it inside react state.
2. access this inside the return statement of the component.
   That will be something like that :

```
const SomeComponent = () => {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState();

  const onClick = async () => {
    const inputSearchData = sessionStorage.getItem("inputData");
    const inputTypeData = sessionStorage.getItem("inputType");

    await axios({
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      method: "GET",
      url: "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search",
      params: {
        q: inputSearchData,
        type: inputTypeData
      }
    })
      .then((res) => {
        setResponse(res);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {/* Access your response state over here */}
      {/* That will be something like that : */}
      {response.map((item, index) => {
        <div key={index}>
          {item.somethingFromYourData}
        </div>
      })}
    </div>
  )
};
```